# How to reference dynamically created Array Checkbox?

Tags: c#, arrays, checkbox, datagridview

I want to make an if-else statement but I don't know how to reference dynamically created array `CheckBoxes`.

Do note that each `CheckBox` made is from a column name of an excel sheet.
[image]

```
CheckBox[] chk = new CheckBox[dt.Columns.Count];


for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Columns.Count - 1; i ++)
{

    chk[i] = new CheckBox();
    chk[i].Name = dt.Columns[i].ColumnName;
    chk[i].Text = dt.Columns[i].ColumnName;
    chk[i].AutoCheck = true;
    chk[i].Bounds = new Rectangle(10, 20 + padding + dynamicHeight, 40, 22);

    panelCol.Controls.Add(chk[i]);
    dynamicHeight += 20;

    panelCol.Size = new Size(120, dynamicHeight);
    panelCol.Controls.Add(chk[i]);

    chk[i].Location = new Point(0, dynamicHeight);
    chk[i].Size = new Size(120, 21);

    panelCol.BackColor = Color.White;
    panelCol.AutoScroll = true;
    // panelCol.AutoScrollMinSize = new Size (0, 1200);
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating new array every loop iteration?

Comment: fixed it now. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make your `chk` variable as public property of your page class. And you can reference it from aspx markup.

Your *.aspx.cs file:

```
public CheckBox[];

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    /* ... other code ... */

    Chk = new CheckBox[dt.Columns.Count];

    for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Columns.Count - 1; i ++)
    {
        Chk [i] = new CheckBox();

        /* ... other code ... */
    }
}
```

Your *.aspx file:

```
<!-- some markup -->

<% if(Chk.Any()) { %>
    <%-- do some work here --%>
<% } else { %>
    <%-- do some other work here --%>
<% } %>

<!-- some other markup -->
```